# Как передать байт в качестве параметра функции(сеттера)

Tags: java, setter

При попытке передать байт в качестве аргумента в функции сеттера вылазит ошибка

> The method setValue(byte) in the type XOGame is not applicable for the arguments (int)

тип `this.value` - `byte`

Вот сама функция

```
public void setValue(byte value) {

    this.value = value;
    switch(this.value) {
    case 0:
        setText(" ");
        break;
    case 1:
        setText("X");
        break;
    case 2:
        setText("O");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Может прикастить `int` к `byte`: `setValue((byte) переменная_типа_int)`

Comment: покажи как ты его передаешь и где получаешь

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
   buttons[i].setValue(0);
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method setValue(byte) in the type XOGame is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Нельзя передавать `int` вместо `byte` (т.к. `byte` меньше `int`) - необходимо приводить тип вручную:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    buttons[i].setValue((byte) 0);
}
```

Если была бы обратная ситуация - атрибут класса имел тип `int`, то вы бы могли передавать `byte` - java сама выполнит приведение меньшего типа к большему, или т.н. *преобразование с расширением* без потери данных (`byte`, `short` к `int`, `int` к `float` и `double` и т.д.).
Аналогичная ситуация происходит, когда при вычислении некоторого выражения используются аргументы различных типов - результат приводит к типу наибольшего размера. Пример из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>       **byte** to **short**, **int**, **long**, **float**, or **double**
>       **short** to **int**, **long**, **float**, or **double**
>       **char** to **int**, **long**, **float**, or **double**
>       **int** to **long**, **float**, or **double**
>       **long** to **float** or **double**
>       **float** to **double**
>   A widening primitive conversion **does not lose information** about the overall magnitude of a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Вызов `setValue()` с аргументом в виде литерала `0` трактуется компилятором как вызов `setValue(int )` - числовые литералы по умолчанию считаются как имеющие тип `int`

Поскольку в Java отсутствует байтовый литерал, то единственный способ это ручной кастинг на `byte` - `setValue((byte )0);`